# How to express this sentence by using quantifiers and logical operators

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Here is the sentence:

There is a shortest person, but there is no tallest person.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to logic and mathematics but not programming.

Comment: discrete math is related to programming

Comment: @Smandoli In zodiac's defense, there is a valid tag with open questions and followers on the subjects (excluding quantifiers).

Answer (score 0):

There exists person where person < i, for all persons i, i != person.

There doesn't exists a person where person > i, for all persons i, i != person.

```
∃p : T(i,p) ∀i, i!=p, i in (x, y, z)

~(∃p : T(p,i) ∀i, i!=p), i in (x y, z)
```

Comment: Thank you. But i have to say sorry, i forgot to say. It is given variable x, y, z and T(x, y) for "x is taller than y". And all variable have to quantified by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
(EXISTS x in People | FORALL y in People \ {x} y TALLER_THAN x)
AND
NOT (EXISTS w in People | FORALL z in People \ {w} w TALLER_THAN z)
```

Some notes:

- "BUT" can usually be translated as "AND NOT", unless the first sentence is a negative, in which case it actually means "AND".
- "THERE IS" can usually be translated as "EXISTS"
- Any superlative (e.g., "MOST" or "BEST" or ending in "-EST") usually means "EXISTS x SUCH THAT FORALL Y =/= x | X MORE ? THAN Y".

Comment: Thank you. But i have to say sorry, i forgot to say. It is given variable x, y, z and T(x, y) for "x is taller than y". And all variable have to quantified by yourself.

Comment: The choice of variables is unimportant. In fact, you only need two variables, `x` and `y`, the `x` and `y` at the beginning will be scoped by the quantifiers they are associated with (they are "bound"), and you can safely  reuse them in the second part. For T(x, y)... just replace `a TALLER_THAN b` with `T(a, b)`.

Comment: @zodiac Did you see my comment?

Answer (score -1):

shortest && !(tallest)

Is this you are expecting

Comment: Thank you. But i have to say sorry, i forgot to say. It is given variable x, y, z and T(x, y) for "x is taller than y". And all variable have to quantified by yourself.